# Mersenne quasi-primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

This question comes out of [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81717/can-we-always-find-such-an-irreducible-polynomial-of-degree-n-where-degreepx-x) (and is a comment to my answer to it, but should be of independent interest: What is known about "Mersenne numbers" (those of the form $2^n-1$) with few divisors (you can define *few* any way you want; I want it to be smaller than the expected number for a number of that size).

Comment: It's Mersenne with an s.

Comment: There's a Lenstra-Pomerance-Wagstaff heuristic for number of Mersenne primes < x, so maybe this can be modified to get what you want? For instance, part of the derivation of the mentioned heuristic involves the point of the probability of a random number of size $2^n-1$ being prime being about $1/(n \log 2)$ (but there are other things also), and just the other day, there was a thread on Math Overflow (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes) on asymptotic density of $k$-almost primes that might be useful here.  